# access data with reference type in firestore

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

What i have in firestore:
I have collection named "calorie" in calorie i have two documents 1)fruits 2)vegetables
in fruits i have property named "veggies" of type `reference` which references to the vegetables document.
[img of firestore database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjahV.png)

What i want to do :
I want to access vegetables data with the reference of veggies in fruits.

What i've tried :

```
getCaloriesbyRef() {

const query = this.afs.collection("calorie").ref.where('veggies', '==', "calorie/vegetables");
return query.get().then(querySnapshot => {
  if (querySnapshot.empty) {
    console.log('no data found');
  } else if (querySnapshot.size > 1) {
    console.log('no unique data');
  } else {
    querySnapshot.forEach(documentSnapshot => {
      console.log(documentSnapshot.ref)
      });
    });
  }
});
}
```

please correct me if i'm wrong anywhere , i don't have much expreriece with firestore
Thanks!!

Comment: Hello, have a look at the duplicate: You have to build a `DocumentReference` and use it in your query.

Comment: it gives me an err : "ERROR FirebaseError: Function Query.where() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a custom object"

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Can you please tell me how i can implement it in my code??

Comment: `const caloriesDocRef = firebase.firestore().collection('calorie').doc('vegetables');  const query = this.afs.collection("calorie").ref.where('veggies', '==', caloriesDocRef);`

Comment: but  it gives me err : "ERROR FirebaseError: Function Query.where() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a custom object" in core.js

Comment: @RenaudTarnec my Code : 
  `const docRef = this.afs.collection("calorie").doc("vegetables");`
   `const query = docRef.collection("calorie").ref.where('veggies','==', docRef)`

Comment: You should do `const query = this.afs.collection(...)...`

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Tried this... `const docRef = this.afs.collection("calorie").doc("vegetables");`
`const query = this.afs.collection("calorie").ref.where('veggies', '==', docRef)`
`return query.get().then(querySnapshot=>{`
`console.log(querySnapshot)`
 `   })`   still getting the same err says "ERROR FirebaseError: Function Query.where() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a custom object" in core.js